how to decode sbus in uart?
I need to read the sbus signal coming from my receiver mc7rb-v2 using raspberry pi 5, I have made a signal inverter as stated in the manual of the receiver and connected to uart pin, I use pyserial to receive data from uart but I don't know how to decode this data
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
     port='/dev/ttyAMA0',
     baudrate = 100000,
     bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
     parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
     stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
     )

while True:
     x=ser.read(25)
     print(x)

output:
b'\x0e\xc0\x02\x1e\x80\x80\x06<\xe0\x00\x02\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

this is not a question about the Raspberry Pi

In addition to whatever your mystery device might do or require, ttyAMA0 is connected to Bluetooth so it is unlikely to work.

@Milliways It does, output i provided is sent by receiver,it is absent when I run code without a connected receiver, and it changes when I press buttons on a RC controller which is connected to said receiver

Your comment is unclear and all the detail belongs in your question. There IS serial on GPIO 14/15 but it is NOT ttyAMA0. You should in any event be using /dev/serial0 although the mini UART does not support parity. If you have a Pi5 and ACTUALLY require advanced serial the Pi has additional serial ports.

@Milliways i'm sorry im a bit confused, i disabled bluetooth in config.txt, wouldn't that make uart available through ttyama0? and any other /dev/*** shows nothing.
thank you for you reply in advance

No! I don't understand why so many people want to swap UART and it CAN be done (but I have never done so) and it requires a couple of steps. The default serial is /dev/serial0 (even if you do swap).
